# Can Play Framework act as a Proxy server or as a Reverse Proxy?

Tags: proxy, playframework, reverse-proxy

I have the client: **C**,
the server: **S** (e.g. on a local ip 10.0.0.1 on port 7000)
and a web server: **W** (e.g. on www.example.com)

C wants to contact the S through a web path: http://www.example.com/path_for_server_S

So W acts as a **Forward Proxy**

Now the S is going to contact C through the same path: http://www.example.com/path_for_server_S

So now W acts as a **Reverse Proxy**

Then in Apache this would be a common configuration like this:

```
ProxyPass /path_for_server_S http://10.0.0.1:7000
ProxyPassReverse /path_for_server_S http://10.0.0.1:7000
```

**Would be possible for Play Framework** who already has a web server built-in to handle this kind of situation?

Searched a lot, found nothing on the matter :)

Comment: Let me make it more clear: I don't mean to user apache or lighthttpd or nginx or etc...
I mean if I can configure play or write some code that would do the same... proxy the request to another server (in this example in 10.0.0.1:7000)

Answer (score 0):

You could certainly write a proxy component manually in any modern web framework, by [triggering an HTTPS request](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/wiki/Javahttp) from a controller then passing the result back in the response.

I'd be surprised if you got Nginx-level performance though.

Comment: Thanks! Since then I have used apache instead and all works well

Comment: Looks like someone has a way to do it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26906543/333643