# Play Framework Scala Proxy For Http Post

Tags: java, scala, playframework, proxy, playframework-2.0

I'm using play! framework with scala and trying to create a proxy for http requests, GET and POST.

The GET actions seems to be working, the issue is with the POST action, where I'm not able to pass the payload of the request.

I tried several things, like the code below, but none seems to be working.

```
  def postAction(query: String) = Action.async { implicit request =>
    val data = if (request.body.asText != None) request.body.asText.get else ""
    WS.url(DEMO_URL + query).post(data).map(resp => Ok(resp.body).as("application/json"))
  }
```

Last thing to mention is that I'm new to both play! and scala.

Comment: Is `query` being passed on correctly?

Comment: You're not adding any headers to your `WS` request. Shouldn't you at least include `Content-Type` ? As of right now, since you're parsing the body of `postAction` as a `String`, the content-type will be `text/plain` by default.

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys, the code above sends the data as a string to the server, but I need it to be sent as Json.

Comment: What is `val data` ? Is that supposed to be JSON?

Comment: 1. "none seems to be working" -- it's helpful to be more specific than "not working." :) 2. Your second line can be written like this: `val data = request.body.asText.getOrElse("")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had to add `parse.json` the Action.async(parse.json)

The code now is much simpler and looks like this:

```
  def postAction(query: String) = Action.async(parse.json) { implicit request =>
    WS.url(DEMO_URL + query).post(request.body).map(resp =>
      Ok(resp.body).as("application/json")
    )
  }
```